# Is it possible to 'Hot Spot or Hot Partition' AWS S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an application which runs on many hosts simultaneously. Each host will query S3 using the same set of pre-signed URLs. This may not happen at the exact time, but for a given presigned url, we would have 50 hosts trying it in the same 1-20 second interval.

I am getting a lot of retries, and high latency (in times of peak TPS for my app, latency has spiked as high as 10-15 seconds).

Our data is in one bucket, the bucket has 32 prefixes (0 - 31) which we call shards, and the producer of the data uses a ConsistentHashing method on a UUID to determine the shard to use.

### Questions

1. How can I determine if I am creating a hot spot?
2. Are there any metrics in the AWS Console that can help me determine this?

Comment: No, there are no "hot partitions" in s3.